# How to use pear mail mime

Tags: php, sendmail

How can you use pear mail mime with google. I found this which lets you use pear mail with google, but not mail mime: http://globalconstant.scnay.com/2009/11/06/sending-email-through-gmail-using-php/

```
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

$from = "Sender <*******@googlemail.com>";
$to = "Receiver <*******@googlemail.com>";
$subject = "Welcome to SITENAME!";
$crlf = "\n";
$html = "<h1> This is HTML </h1>";

$headers = array('From' => $from,
                 'To' => $to,
                 'Subject' => $subject);


$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$port = 465;
$username = "********@googlemail.com";
$password = "********";

$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);

$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);

$smtp = Mail::factory("smtp",array("host" => $host,
                      "port" => $port,
                      "auth" => true,
                      "username" => $username,
                      "password" => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo $mail->getMessage();
} else {
echo "Message sent successfully!";
}
echo "\n";
```

I keep getting

> Failed to add recipient: @localhost
>   [SMTP: Invalid response code received
>   from server (code: 555, response:
>   5.5.2 Syntax error. f52sm5542930wes.35)]

**Edit:**

The email is now received, however it turns out like this:

```
This is a message I sent from <a href=3D"http://www.php.net/">PHP</a> using=
 the PEAR Mail package and SMTP through Gmail. Enjoy!
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: @Pekka: I think @john means he wishes to send HTML e-mail.

Comment: Sorry, the PHP code didn't show up, damn Markdown, its there now. Yes, I want to send a HTML email. ^

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have an issue with the email header. I updated your code based on the pear mail doc (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php):

```
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

$from = "Sender <*******@googlemail.com>";
$to = "Receiver <*******@googlemail.com>";
$subject = "Welcome to SITENAME!";
$crlf = "\n";
$html = "<h1> This is HTML </h1>";

$headers = array('From' => $from,
                 'To' => $to,
                 'Subject' => $subject);


//$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // try this one to use ssl
$port = 465;
$username = "********@googlemail.com";
$password = "********";

//$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime =  new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf)); //based on pear doc     
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);

//$body = $mime->get();
$body = $mime->getMessageBody(); //based on pear doc above
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);

$smtp = Mail::factory("smtp",array("host" => $host,
                      "port" => $port,
                      "auth" => true,
                      "username" => $username,
                      "password" => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo $mail->getMessage();
} else {
echo "Message sent successfully!";
}
echo "\n";
```

It works for me so I hope it will work for you!
Cheers,
Erez

Answer (score 2):

@john: Using the code from the link you posted, modify it like so --

```
<?php
require_once('Mail.php');
require_once('Mail/mime.php');

$from = 'Sender <sender@gmail.com>';
$to = 'Receiver <receiver@something.com>';
$subject = 'Sent from PHP on my machine';

$text = 'This is a message I sent from <a href="http://www.php.net/">PHP</a> '
      . 'using the PEAR Mail package and SMTP through Gmail. Enjoy!';

$message = new Mail_mime();
$message->setTXTBody(strip_tags($text)); // for plain-text
$message->setHTMLBody($text);
$body = $message->get();

$host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$port = 587; //According to Google you need to use 465 or 587
$username = 'sender';
$password = 'your_password';

$headers = array('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array(
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo $mail->getMessage();
} else {
    echo "Message sent successfully!";
}

echo "\n";

?>
```

**Update:**

> **Edit:**
>
> The email is now received, however it turns out like this:
>
> ```
> This is a message I sent from <a href=3D"http://www.php.net/">PHP</a> using=
> the PEAR Mail package and SMTP through Gmail. Enjoy!
> ```

@john: Update

```
$body = $mime->get();
```

to

```
$body = $mime->get(array('text_charset' => 'utf-8'));
```

and try again.

Comment: Probably an accurate guess. +1

Comment: I still get emails like this: <html><body>Dear member,In order to validate your account please click=
 on the following link: <br/><a href=3D"?action=3Dverify&id=3D33c292bcfc377=
818a43a1cfb6f470bf91f59e556c221c13a97c326f47c6c00b7">?action=3Dverify&id=3D=
33c292bcfc377818a43a1cfb6f470bf91f59e556c221c13a97c326f47c6c00b7</a>. Enjoy=
!</body></html>

Answer (score 1):

```
$body = $mime->get(array('text_charset' => 'utf-8'));
```

In addition to the above you need html_charset for html emails.

```
$crlf = "\n";

$body = $mime->get(array('html_charset' => 'utf-8', 'text_charset' => 'utf-8', 'eol' => $crlf));
```

This will fix the abberations like Â in the e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't comment on StealthyNinja's answer so I posted my own, sorry about that.

The question is also a bit old but I maybe this could be useful to others.

To get rid of all that HTML tags and weird characters you have to prepare your header so the e-mail client can read the e-mail right. Try this **AFTER** setting your $headers array:

```
$headers = $message->headers($headers);
```

It should work ok after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to remove 3D after = sign.

```
$hdrs = array( 'From'    => $from,
       'To'      => $to,
       'Subject' => $subject  );

$mime =& new Mail_mime();
$mime->setTXTBody($message);

if($htmlMessage==""){
    $htmlMessage=$message;
}

$mime->setHTMLBody($htmlMessage);
if($attachmentIsFile){
    if($attachment!=null)
        $mime->addAttachment($attachment,'application/octet-stream',$attachmentName.extractExtension($attachment));
}else{
    if($attachment!="")
        $mime->addAttachment($attachment,'application/octet-stream',$attachmentName,false);
}
$body = $mime->get(array('text_encoding' => '8bit','html_encoding' => '8bit'));
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);
```